# How to prove for the continuity for such a function below

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $x,y$ be vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $f:\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow\mathbb R$. Suppose $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=0$. Also, $f(x+y)\le f(x)+f(y)$.

I only find that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$
But I have no clue for $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$f(x+y)-f(x) \le f(y)$.

If we can show that
$f(x+y)-f(x) \ge - f(y)$
we are done.

Putting $x-y$ for $x$,
the condition becomes
$f(x) \le f(x-y)+f(y)$
or 
$f(x-y)-f(x) \ge -f{y)$.

Putting $-y$ for $y$,
this is
$f(x+y)-f(x) \ge -f{-y)$
which gives us what we want.

I.e.,
$-f(-y) \le f(x+y)-f(x)
\le f(y)$.

Comment: It did help to understand the above answer thx a lot